# How to disable all commands at once with a single command

Tags: discord.py

I would like to find a way to disable all commands at once using discord.py, I'm semi-new to discord.py and I have not found a way to get it working yet. Here is my code below:

```
ID='no'
...............
@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def nocmdrun(self,ctx):   
    global ID
    ID = "yes"
    await ctx.send('No Command Run has been activated.')

@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def yescmdrun(self,ctx):
    try:
        global ID
        ID = "no"
        await ctx.send('No Command Run has been deactivated.')
    except:
        await ctx.send('Failed to deactivate No Command Run.')



def is_no_cmd_run_activated(self):
    global ID
    ID = "no"   
   


@commands.command()
@commands.check(is_no_cmd_run_activated)
async def tester(self,ctx):
    await ctx.send('congrats')
```

(This is in a cog called developer.py)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add `import os` to the beginning of your main `.py` file. Then, to load and unload all your cog commands, add this code into the main `.py` file:

```py
@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx):
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    await ctx.send('commands unloaded successfully.')
```

Also, make sure that the folder that your cog files are in is named `cogs`.
If you want to create a command to load all of the cog commands, you can simply do this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def load(ctx):
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    await ctx.send('commands loaded successfully.')
```

Comment: Is there a way to possibly do this without unloading cogs? If there isn't how would I add a special error to inform the command author that commands are currently disabled?